# select max id in mysql nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs

I want to get max id from mysql, but I keep getting error.

**abc.jsx**

```
async function mintNFT() {
    let id = await getNumberOfRow()
    console.log("this is id", id)
    return id;
}

async function getNumberOfRow() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:4000/getNumberOfRow").then(response => {
            console.log("response ", response.data[0])
            return response.data[0];
        })
        .then(posts => {
            return posts[0]
        })
        .then((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    return;
}
```

**index.js**

```
app.get("/getNumberOfRow", (req, res) => {
    db.query("SELECT MAX(id) FROM  NFTDetails", (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        res.send(result)
    });
})
```

**Output**

```
this is id undefined
Minter.jsx:47 response  {MAX(id): 154}
Minter.jsx:54 undefined
```

I have added `async-await`, why it still displays "this is id" first ? How can I fix it so I can get the max id?

---

**Edit**

After I edited my code to this, I get different output.

```
async function getNumberOfRow() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/getNumberOfRow");
    console.log("response ",response.data[0])
    return response.data[0][0]; // you could extract the first part to a variable `posts`, but doing so just adds a variable
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
response  {MAX(id): 154}MAX(id): 154[[Prototype]]: Object
Minter.jsx:32 this is id undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the call to `axios.get` in `getNumberOfRow`, and it doesn't need to be async based on how you're handling it.

```js
function getNumberOfRow() {
  return axios.get("http://localhost:4000/getNumberOfRow").then(response => {
    console.log("response ",response.data[0])
    return response.data[0]["MAX(id)"];
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
}
```

As an `async` function, you would write it like this.

```js
async function getNumberOfRow() {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:4000/getNumberOfRow");
    console.log("response ",response.data[0])
    return response.data[0]["MAX(id)"]; // you could extract the first part to a variable `posts`, but doing so just adds a variable
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks, I have edited my post..How can I get this output _this is id 154_ ?

Comment: @Hoo you made another typo, you had `.then((err) =>` instead of `.catch((err) =>`. Using `.then` took the `id`, printed it (you assigned the variable name `err`, though it is not an error),  then discarded it.

Comment: I'm using your second async function, but `response.data[0][0];` not returning 154.

Comment: `response.data[0][0];` is returning undefined

Comment: This is based on your code. Try `response.data[0]["MAX(id)"]`

Comment: `.then(posts => {})` is not required here, as access to the response property is not asynchronous.  The `.then` return can be the same as the `async` version.